# How do I count all files in all sub folders in a directory and its sub folders but return the name of the sub folder with a count of the files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hoping someone can help me out here. I have a folder which holds a number of sub folders - e.g.:

> ```
> Business
> Chemistry
> DT
> English
> ```

Each one of those folders has a number of sub folders.

What I would like to do is to run a batch file which would then output something like this:

> ```
> Business: 24
> Chemistry: 542
> DT: 298
> English: 101
> ```

I have a command line command, which when run in the sub folder, returns the number of files in that folder and sub folders, but this is quite a laborious process to have to run the command 50+ times.

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40150480/edit) your question and post what you have tried as code until now !

Answer (score 0):

Give a try for this batch file :

```dos
@echo off
(
    FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO (
        PUSHD "%%G"
        FOR /F "delims=" %%H in ('dir /a-d /b * ^|find /C /V ""') DO echo %%G : %%H
        POPD
        )
 )>"..\count.txt"
 Start "" "..\count.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, *(and should be relatively quick for larger directories)*:

```cmd
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(Set selDir=C:\Users\Robert\Subjects)

For /D %%A In ("%selDir%\*") Do Call :Sub "%%A"
Timeout -1 1>Nul
Exit/B

:Sub
Set i=3
For /F "EOL=- Tokens=1-3" %%A In (
    'RoboCopy /L /E /NFL /NDL /NJH %1 null *.*') Do (
    If %%B==: (Set/A i-=1
        If !i! Equ 1 Echo(%~nx1 : %%C))
```

Just make sure you change the path within the parentheses on line four to suit your parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your directories are located in `D:\root\`, the following counts the immediate sub-directories of each:

```dos
@echo off
for /D %%R in ("D:\root\*") do (
    set "NAME=%%~nxR"
    set /A "COUNT=0"
    for /D %%D in ("%%~fR\*") do (
        set /A "COUNT+=1"
    )
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!NAME!: !COUNT!
    endlocal
)
```